# Write a program that asks the user to give the initial value of variable X. As long ad the variable is less than 100 it keep doubling its value

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

// Hi there, I'm new to programming and I'm starting off with C++;

// The program for the task must be written using a while loop only; but I am open to any other ways of writing the program; this is what I have so far, but whenever I insert x it only doubles once and keeps repeating the result without doubling.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x = 0, ind = 2, prod;

cout << " Hey! What's the initial value of your variable ? ";
cin >> x;

while (x < 100)
{   
    prod = x * ind;             
    cout << prod;
}

return 0;
}
```

— Regards

Comment: `while (x < 100)` where in that loop do you *ever* perform any action that would change the value of `x`, and as such the possible result of that conditional expression? The entire loop body could simply be `std::cout << (x *= ind) << '\n';`

Comment: So where do you expect it to double `x`?

Comment: You're never updating/doubling the actual value of x.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you so much for clarifying that, I had actually done that before but I forgot to declare my variable so I was getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the output in the variable `x` and keep  checking it.

```
while (x < 100)
{   
    x = x * ind;             
    cout << x;
}
```

Comment: Or equivalent shorthand, e.g. `x *= ind;`

Comment: Or even more shorthand: `cout << (x *= ind);`.